# import jQuery-ui and jQuery with npm install

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, npm

Somewhat new to npm here..

I'd like to use jQuery-ui in my project. I'm used to importing both jQuery and jQuery-ui with a script tag in my HTML, but I would like to import both using npm install.

I got jQuery working with.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

But whenever I try to import `jquery-ui` I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

There's a lot of posts about this error. But all of them seem to be centered around people just putting their script tags for jQuery and jQuery-ui in the wrong order.

I can't find anything on how to install both jQuery and jQuery-ui with npm install?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the browser or Node.js ?

Comment: I am using Node.js

Comment: For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom. Form more details please refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: jQuery seems to work fine though. I might be confusing Node.js with npm... I am not using an official build tool. But one given to me. I am working on a website project and jQuery works fine. I just can't seem to get jQuery ui imported correctly?

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-es6-project-using-babel-browserify/

Comment: I read through it, but It doesn't tell me how I would go about importing a plugin/addon to another import? All my normal imports are working fine. It's just jQuery UI, where it says `jQuery is not defined`, despite having jQuery importing in the line above :( To clarify, I am all set up. My project requirements are all done. I just want to make some UI Improvements, where jQuery UI would be very helpful.

Comment: [similar question](/q/40858756)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just tried updating **jquery** (to 3.1.0) & **jquery-ui** (to 1.12.0) and got the very same error.

Newer versions of **jquery-ui** seems to require a global `jQuery` variable to initialize or newer versions of **jquery** does not set the `jQuery` global variable by default anymore, hence the *Uncaught ReferenceError*.

A clear solution is to set `global.jQuery = require('jquery')` before importing **jquery-ui**.

It does not seem to work for **browserify** though, since **browserify** prioritizes imports over other expressions (imports are placed on top of the browserified code even if they were placed behind other expressions in the original code).

So if you're using **browserify**, try **jquery**@2.2.4 and **jquery-ui**@1.10.5, then import as:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Works with laravel/gulp/webpack. Just wish I found this 3 hours earlier!

Comment: when using jquery-ui with webpack, any idea why it's not possible to import global functions like Sine, Circ, Elastic, Back, Bounce https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect.js#L932 ?? when I try to import, these functions are always undefined. I've tried different ways `import {Sine} from 'jquery-ui'` or `import {Sine} from 'jquery-ui/ui/effect'` - it is undefined in either case. I'm disappointed. Please advise.

Answer (score 10):

Using with webpack.

`import $ from 'jquery'` pass jquery module default property to $, so that you can use $ as a *local variable* in your current module. However jquery-ui only supports amd, so when you use `import`, it will use global `jQuery` as $ inside and run a function in the constructor of the module (you can look into its source code).

So what to do? Make `jQuery` as a *global variable*.

My way using webpack:

1 only import the module which you want to use

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/datepicker.css'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css'
```

2 webpack config

```
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'windows.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
}
```

ProvidePlugin provide a way to make variables to be global variables. So after you use ProvidePlugin, here `$` `jQuery` `window.jQuery` can be used directly in a module even you have no `import $ from 'jquery'`.

> ProvidePlugin: Automatically load modules instead of having to import or require them everywhere.

However, if you do not use webpack, just remember that you should provide a global variable `jQuery`. For example:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = $
```

put this code in your entry code. It is dependent on what compile system you are using.

Comment: For Webpack you can use resolve in order to force all your packages to use the same version of jquery

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using the [parcel.js](https://parceljs.org/) bundler, all the standard suggestions/solutions wont work if you use `import`:

For example:

```
//
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
import "jquery-ui-bundle";

// or something like, as suggested/standard
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/selectable.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable';
```

**wont seem to work**, with error jQuery is undefined, since the library that depends on jQuery does so in a sync way, and because parceljs ends up generating the following:

```
"use strict";
var _ = _interopRequireDefault(require("jquery"));
require("jquery-ui-bundle");
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
window.$ = window.jQuery = _.default;
```

assigning jQuery on window happens too late.

The fix is to use `require` over `import` (simple but not obvious)

```
const $ = require("jquery");
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
require("jquery-ui-bundle");
```

then parceljs will generate, which will then work

```
var $ = require("jquery");
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
require("jquery-ui-bundle");
```