# How to install a Javascript library on VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use the Sortable plugin from jQueryUI in my VueJS project, but I don't know how to include libraries on a VueJS 2 project.

This is what I have done so far:

1) Installed jQuery and jQueryUI this way

```
 npm install --save jquery-ui
 npm install --save jquery
```

2) I add these lines to main.js:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = $.extend(require('jquery-ui'));
```

3) I use like this on my component:

```
<div class="height">
   <app-component-component></app-component-component>
</div>

....

export default {
    components: {
        appComponentComponent: ComponentComponent
    },
    ...
    mounted() {
        $('.height').sortable();  
    }       
}
```

But I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function"
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in order to import and use the library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you not simply import / extend jQuery in your component instead of globally?

Comment: @Phil can you please tell me how to do that? I tried to add the scripts to the component but it didn't work

Comment: Well, in the `<script>` section of your component, something like this ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417328/import-jquery-ui-and-jquery-with-npm-install

Comment: @Phil I added    import $ from 'jquery'; import 'jquery-ui'; to the script section but I still have the same error :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your sortable plugin code in updated() method of vue lifecycle.

```
updated()
    {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            jQuery('.height').sortable();
        })
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I replaced the mounted method by the updated you suggested but I still have the same error

Comment: did you check your source that you have jquery included or not ? and yeah one more thing instead of $('.height').sortable(); try jQuery('.height').sortable()

Comment: I think the libraries were added to the project because I do CTRL-U and then search jqueryui and I see that it was added

Comment: did you try jQuery instead of $ ? I updated my answer

Comment: yes I get the error [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: jQuery(...).sortable is not a function"

Comment: can you try to put your jquery UI js under the compiled app.js?

Comment: sorry ankit but I don't know how to do that

Comment: instead of adding jquery ui using npm. just grab the live source of jquery UI and add that after your compiled app.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in main.js

```
 global.jQuery = require('jquery');
 var $ = global.jQuery;
 window.$ = $;
 require('jquery-ui');
 require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable');
```

And you can use it inside mounted as you are.